# Preserve escaped characters when reading csv with pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading in a csv file like this:

```
label, text
a, 'here\'s some text\nwith a new line'
b, 'and some more\nwith a new line'
```

I'm currently reading it in like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, quotechar="'", escapechar="\\")
```

The data frame is created with the text including just a 'n' character where the `\n` is supposed to be.

> 'here's some textnwith a new line'
>   'and some morenwith a new line'

How do I preserve other escaped characters, like \n, when I'm reading in a csv to a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can always just replace \'s after reading the CSV:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(r"\\\'s", "'s", regex=True)
print(df)

  label                                  text
0     a   'here's some text\nwith a new line'
1     b      'and some more\nwith a new line'
```